# Changing string in Pandas while keeping variable

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My data in Pandas (df['case']) contains two ways of referring to an amount of money in USD:

- He payed USD500 for the PC.
- He payed USD 500 for the PC.
- The transaction was done in USD and in EUR.

The difference is in the Blank. I would now like to replace 'USD ' with 'USD', but only if USD is followed by a number - while keeping the number.

```
df['case'] = df['case'].str.replace('USD ', 'USD', re.IGNORECASE)
```

will not work, as it will also include instances where it is not followed by a number (see third example).

```
df['case'] = df['case'].str.replace('USD (\d+)', 'USD', re.IGNORECASE)
```

This will match only cases in which it is followed by a number but also replace the number. Is there a way of telling it to find the variable and then replace everything but the variable? Basically:

```
df['case'] = df['case'].str.replace('USD (\d+)', 'USD(\d+)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

were the second (\d+) is not taken literally but as a place holder for the number from before that will be inserted here again.

I also tried:

```
for row in df['case'].str.contains('USD (\d+), re.IGNORECASE):
   df['case'] = df['case'].str.replace('USD ', 'USD', re.IGNORECASE)
```

The latter didn't work to iterate over rows and only perform the changes in the row that contained the string. A solution for the latter would help a great deal with also other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(?i)USD\s+(?=\d)
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - enable case insensitive search
- `USD` - a literal `USD`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?=\d)` - (a positive lookahead making sure) the next char should be a digit that won't be added to the match value and thus won't be replaced.

In Pandas:

```
df['case'] = df['case'].str.replace(r'(?i)USD\s+(?=\d)', 'USD')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5MnR86/2)

**If you need to keep `USD` in its original case**, use

```
df['case'] = df['case'].str.replace(r'(?i)(USD)\s+(?=\d)', r'\1')
```

that is, capture the `USD` into a capturing group, and then use a `\1` backreference/placeholder referring to that group value from the string replacement pattern.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I did already, but unfortunately it is not counted as I have too little reputation :(. They said they will count it internally, though.